# How to change current page link colours?

Tags: html, css

so I've tried a few different things out. But ultimately no success. I'm trying to change the colour of the "Home" link to stay a different colour than the rest when we are specifically on the homepage. So for example, say I'm on the homepage, I specifically want that colour to be orange for the home link, and then when I click on About link, about link changes to orange and the home goes to default white

Html:

```
<!--Header-->
        <header class="header-main">
            <!--Navigation menu-->
            <nav class="navigation">
                <!--Bakingwithwill Logo-->
                <img class="logo" src="imgs/bww.png" alt="Bakingwithwill" />
                <!--Navigation links-->
                <div class="nav-links">
                    <!--Unordered list of navigation items-->
                    <ul class="nav-menu">
                        <a href="#"><li id="active-home" class="nav-items">Home</li></a>
                        <a href="about.html"><li class="nav-items">About</li></a>
                        <a href="order.html"><li class="nav-items">Order</li></a>
                        <a href="contact.html"><li class="nav-items">Contact</li></a>
                        <a href="#"><li class="nav-items">Cart</li></a>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="footer-nav">
                <!--Footer portion of the side navbar-->
                <div class="nav-social">
                <!--Navigation of Bakingwithwill social media accounts-->
                    <ul class="nav-social-list">
                        <li class="social-icons">
                            <a href="https://www.facebook.com/bakingwithwill" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-facebook"></i></a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="social-icons">
                            <a href="https://www.instagram.com/bakingwithwill/" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>

                <p class="copyright">Copyright Bakingwithwill</p>
                <!--Copyright-->
                </div>
            </nav>
            <img class="header-banner" src="imgs/bww-home-banner.jpg" alt="Bakingwithwill bread banner"/>
                <!--Main image-->
                <div class="main">
                <!--Contents outside the side navbar representing header page-->
                    <h2 class="baking-heading">Bakingwithwill</h2>
                    <h1 class="welcome-heading">Welcome!</h1>
                    <h2 class="intro-heading">Get a slice of the best bread in<br>
                        Chatham-Kent!</h2>
                </div>
        </header>
```

CSS:

```
/*Base styles*/
body {
    font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
}

h1 {
    font-family: 'Satisfy', cursive;
}

/*Home styles*/
header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 585px;
}

/*Side bar navigation menu*/
.navigation {
    height: 100%;
    width:160px;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #3D3732;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    padding-top: 20px;
    opacity: 90%;
}

.navigation a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

.logo {
    border-radius: 50%;
    height: 70px;
    width: 70px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-left: 45px;
}

#active-home:link, #active-home:visited {
    color:#E88F2A !important;
}

.navigation li, p {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
}

.navigation .nav-items {
    padding-right: 30px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    text-align: center;
}

.navigation .social-icons {
    list-style-type: none;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline;
    font-size: 15px;
    padding: 5px;
    margin-top: 50px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    margin-left: 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.navigation li:hover {
    color: #E88F2A;
}

.navigation p {
    font-size: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 6px 8px 6px 16px;
}

.main {
    margin-left: 160px;
    padding: 0px 10px;
}

.footer-nav {
    margin-top: 200px;
}

/*Social media icons*/
.navigation i {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

.navigation i:hover {
    color: #E88F2A;
}

/*Text overlaying the image*/
.baking-heading {
    color: #E88F2A;
    font-family: 'Satisfy', cursive;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 40px;
    padding-left: 50px;
    font-size: 50px;
}

.welcome-heading, .intro-heading {
    font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
    position: relative;
}

.welcome-heading, .baking-heading {
    transform: rotate(-13deg);
}

.welcome-heading {
    padding-left: 130px;
    font-size: 50px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

.intro-heading {
    padding-top: 200px;
    font-size: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

.header-banner {
    /*Image styles*/
    margin-top: -40px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 585px;
}
```

Comment: make the color change through a class. The n add this class hardcoded into every page.

Comment: This can't be done with pure CSS. You need to use JavaScript. I suggest you look at this [link](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_active_element.asp)

Comment: why use JS? its not a SPA so he can simply add the class as HTML for every single page

Answer (score 0):

> So for example, say I'm on the homepage, I specifically want that
> colour to be orange for the home link, and then when I click on About
> link, about link changes to orange and the home goes to default white

One **CSS-only** approach is to:

- add a class to the `<body>` element of each page
- add classes to each of your links (or to the list-items containing the links)

**Home Page:**

```
<body class="home-page">

<ul class="nav-menu">
  <li class="nav-items home"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li class="nav-items about"><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
  <li class="nav-items order"><a href="order.html">Order</a></li>
  <li class="nav-items contact"><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
  <li class="nav-items cart"><a href="#">Cart</a></li>                    
</ul>
```

**About Page:**

```
<body class="about-page">

<ul class="nav-menu">
  <li class="nav-items home"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li class="nav-items about"><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
  <li class="nav-items order"><a href="order.html">Order</a></li>
  <li class="nav-items contact"><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
  <li class="nav-items cart"><a href="#">Cart</a></li>                    
</ul>
```

Then you can change the color of the relevant link on each page:

```
.nav-items a {
  color: white;
}

.home-page .nav-items.home a,
.about-page .nav-items.about a {
  color: orange;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a class to the active link and #id is not recommended for styling. Also, the pseudo classes that you're using is blocking your desired outcome. Try changing :

```
#active-home:link, 
#active-home:visited {
    color: #e88f2a !important;
}
```

to:

```
.active {
    color: #e88f2a !important;
}
```

Afterwards, place the .active class into your link code for each page. So for home it would be:

```
  <a href="#"><li class="nav-items active">Home</li></a>
```

and for your about page:

```
<a href="#">
  <li class="nav-items">Home</li>
</a>
<a href="about.html">
  <li class="nav-items active">About</li>
</a>
```

and so on...